# Correct passing struct to FindText function using PInvoke

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

I am using this code to call **FindText** function (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646918.aspx) from Comdlg32.dll:

```
delegate IntPtr FRHookProc(IntPtr hdlg, uint uiMsg, IntPtr wParam,
IntPtr lParam);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
struct FINDREPLACE
{
public uint lStructSize;
public IntPtr hwndOwner;
public IntPtr hInstance;
public uint Flags;
public IntPtr lpstrFindWhat;
public IntPtr lpstrReplaceWith;
public ushort wFindWhatLen;
public ushort wReplaceWithLen;
public IntPtr lCustData;
public FRHookProc lpfnHook;
public IntPtr lpTemplateName;
}

[DllImport("comdlg32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr FindText(ref FINDREPLACE lpfr);


    public void SearchText(string text)
    {
        try
        {
            _lpfrStruct.hwndOwner = _windowHandle;
            _lpfrStruct.lpstrFindWhat = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(text);
            _lpfrStruct.wFindWhatLen = (ushort)text.Length;
            //_lpfrStruct.lStructSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(_lpfrStruct);

            _ptrFindTextHandle = FindText(ref _lpfrStruct);

            if(_ptrFindTextHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                int error = CommDlgExtendedError();
                Debug.WriteLine("[VI] Cannot create FindText dialog, error: " + error.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
```

I suppose the line *//_lpfrStruct.lStructSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(_lpfrStruct);* is an issue

If commented out the CommDlgExtendedError returns 1 (CDERR_STRUCTSIZE = 0x0001 - The lStructSize member of the initialization structure for the corresponding common dialog box is invalid.) when I keep it I get an Exception (writing to protected memory).

Comment: You have to set the struct size. Don't comment that out. But you have to initialize the struct properly which you aren't doing. Surely there's a wrapper for this dialog in .net.

Comment: OK, is it possible to post whole example?

Comment: Did you read the documentation at all. For `lpstrFindWhat` it says, "The buffer should be at least 80 characters long.". The buffer length is measured in bytes not characters, `CharSet.Auto` will give you 2 byte UTF-16 characters on Windows. You did not allocate a buffer for `lpstrReplaceWith`. And finally, we cannot see where your struct was allocated because you only provided partial code. A [mcve[ would clarify all of this. You have enough experience here by now to know better. Please remedy the deficiencies of the question and it will be easy to help you.